# Multiple spans in one line

Tags: html, css

I have following type of html and I to align it in one line. First span is of short/long text, second span is of button and third span is of lines.

```
<h2>
<span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</span>
<span><button>
Deactivate
</button></span>
<span>
  Lines
</span>
</h2>
```

Currently right button and lines span changes its position according to first span text length.

First text can be change, it may be short or long. So I need like its fixed width so that it will change in that only. Right button and lines span will not change according to first text.

I am not good at css at all, just know basics. I am confused how I can adjust those spans to come in one line. I am guessing that all spans and parent h2 tag will need some css (display:flex etc) but don't know how and what else will need to achieve that.

Sorry I could not able to recreate exact html and css that I have. Above is example of it.

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/n_m_t/9gj8dpLa/1/

Comment: for h2 try display:inline;   but your first span is too large, it may not fit to one line

Comment: @ganesh : Don't use <h2> as a container like a <div> tag!
<h2> is made for containing titles like <h1>, <h3> ...
This is a bad practice.

Comment: @ganesh if You want to use display:flex etc, please provide some code and tell us where is Your problem to avoid an unclear question.
Make this step by step... 
Try an answer, then ask a more specific question if You're in trouble...

Answer (score 0):

just use display:block and width:max-content in span tag then check
if you want to width according to screen so use just display:flex

```js
  <h2>
        <span style="display: block;width: max-content;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries </span>
        <span><button>
        Deactivate
        </button></span>
        <span>
          Lines
        </span>
        </h2>
```

Comment: I think will need css for spans also. please check fiddle added

Comment: if you want to display all text in one line then use display:block and width: max-content in  first span check now edit code

Comment: ganesh check this https://jsfiddle.net/2r0xgpyt/

Comment: actually because of  'width: max-content' it shows horizontal scroll. I need like text wrap for first span and other two spans will have fixed position so that depending on text change of first span those will not change.

Comment: so just remove width:max-content

Answer (score 0):

You can set h2 as `flex` and let the first `span` to take up available space.

CSS

```
h2 {
   display: flex;
}
h2 span:first-child{
   flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You're OK to make the first line scrollable, You may try this (EDIT 2 JS added to see the changes between long and short text on div1 and 3 when the button is pressed) :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Scroll and align text</title>
    <style>
        h1{
            padding: 10px;
        }
        h2{
            padding: 10px;
        }
        b{
            color:indianred
        }
        .container{
            position:absolute;
            margin-left: 5%;
            margin-right: 5%;
            width:90%;
            border:1px solid #000000;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, "sans-serif";
        }
        .longText{
            position:relative;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            height:100px;
            width:300px;
            float:left;
            clear:right;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .floating-button{
            position:relative;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            height:auto;
            width:auto;
            float:left;
            clear:right;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .floating-left{
            position:relative;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            height:auto;
            width:auto;
            float:left;
            clear:right;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        let initText=true;
        let short1 = short2 = "<b>Short text : </b>Hello world!";
        let long1 = long2 = "<b>Long text : </b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.";
        
        function foo(){
            if(initText == false){
                document.getElementById("short-long1").innerHTML = short1;
                document.getElementById("short-long1").style.overflowX = "auto";
                document.getElementById("short-long1").style.overflowY = "auto";
                document.getElementById("short-long2").innerHTML = long2;
                initText = !initText;
            }else{
                document.getElementById("short-long1").innerHTML = long1;
                document.getElementById("short-long2").style.overflowX = "auto";
                document.getElementById("short-long2").style.overflowY = "auto";
                document.getElementById("short-long2").innerHTML = short2;
                initText = !initText;
            }
            
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Title 1</h1> <!-- Only one h1 tag MAIN TITLE! -->
        <h2>title 2</h2> <!-- h2 Only for important short text (not for buttons...) -->
        <div id="short-long1" class="longText">

        </div>
        <div class="floating-button">
            <button onClick="foo();">
                Click to change text.
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="short-long2" class="longText">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        foo();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You may also change the style via Javascript for each element ( like here / update sry ;) ).
If short text is displayed, remove the attributes to scroll...

Best regards.

Comment: @ganesh :  <h2> stands only for important short descriptions not for a block with different elements like text + button + ...
So I changed Your <h2> tag as well as the <span> tags.

Comment: You may also change the css with javascript by using document.getElementById("element").style ... check it here : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
h2 {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

this is supposed to keep them on the same line,
but if it doesn't work try this:

```
h2 {
    display: inline;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: That keeps h2 as a block what it shouldn't be.
I'm curious about some precisions in the code, and a little bit of css code before to understand the big figure @Mohamad Khali and ganesh. An <h2> tag is definitely not supposed to be used as a container!!!
AMO he wants to show the long text and the button on the same line...